# Remove item by index while iterating list Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am trying to build shopping cart using Python 3. I could remove item by item name but I tried to remove item by index while iterating through a cart with the below code.

```
def removeItem(index):
clear_output()
for index in range(len(cart)):
    try:
        cart.pop(index)
        #del cart[index]
        print('{} has been remove from cart.'.format(index))
    except:
        print('Sorry we could not remove that item.')
```

I add two items into the cart: bacon and egg. then I show the cart:

```
def showCart():
clear_output()
if cart:
    print('Here is your cart:')
    for item in cart:
        #print('- {}'.format(item))
        print(cart.index(item)+1, item) # show item with index
else:
    print('Your cart is empty.')
```

Then, I tried to remove an item from cart with its index (which begin with 1 as in showCart() function), however, it always removes the first item and the output:

```
0 has been remove from cart.
Sorry we could not remove that item.
```

please let me know if my question is not clear enough.

Comment: I looked it but I want to remove item by its index

Comment: Could you provide a minimal working example maybe? What clear_output() does exactly?

Comment: Hi kalzso, please refer to this link : https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/72307/IPython.display.clear_output

Comment: @MikeB: no, no matter *how* you remove items, the underlying problem is the same: **changing a list while you are iterating over it**. You should not do that. Pure logic may help you understand it, but if not: for each `index` that you are looping over, print out its value *and* the entire cart contents. You will see the loop gets wonky after the very first `pop`. (By the way, isn't that why you *had* to add that `try`? Just to make it not error out? This is why it did that!)